# question on JavaDoCS API

Tags: java

Just start to learn Java, and always see some tutorials mentioning, "using the javaDoCs API to find...",  what does "JavaDoCS API" stands for? Where to find it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Javadocs are a way to write documents inside your code, that can be made into a little framed report dealio.

So for Java itself, you can get the Java 6 API at http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/

if you are using say, Spring and someone says look at the JavaDocs API.. you would have to go google (or use something like Maven) to get the javadocs into your app.

Edit - Javadoc FAQ: http://java.sun.com/j2se/javadoc/faq/index.html

Answer (score 1):

Javadocs are standard documentation pages generated from special comments inserted directly in the code.
You can find the whole thing for the standard API here: http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/

Most IDES will also show you the API when you hit ctrl+space. 
You will need the documentation or source files for non standard apis such as libraries / frameworks / etc.